# Which layout type to use for creating this interface?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create the left layout from this link
[Blog App User Interface
by Thomas Budiman on Dribbble.com](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/153277/screenshots/2315865/attachments/439623/fullpixels.png)

I have followed this https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView tutorial and I am now able to design heterogenous layouts inside RecyclerView

Actually I need help to figure out,

1. Whether RecyclerView is the right choice to create such layout ? (I'm trying to create a blog app and my activity is supposed to show list of blog posts, in the manner shown in Dribbble screenshot.)
2. If yes, then what logic can be used to achieve it? (acc to me `getItemViewType` should be responsible to tell what layout to use. )

Any help would be be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a LinearLayout to contain this view which has a padding like this:

```
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="16dp"
  ...
     >
    <ImageView>
    <TextVeiw android:id="@+id/title">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/body">
    <FrameLayout
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/gray"
     />
    <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     ...
     >
        <ImageView
         android:layout_weight="1" />
        <FrameLayout
         android:layout_width="1dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@color/gray"
     />
        <ImageView
         android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And if you want it to be repeated just use a RecyclerView. If you have any questions you can ask.

Comment: Thanks for answering and providing the directions :)  Actually the thing is, I have an ArrayList of objects of a class 'Blog', and I want to display the elements of that arrayList in the recyclerView, How should I proceed with making the recyclerView such that one element of the arrayList get layout1 , then consecutive two other elements of arrayList get layout2, then the next element should get layout1 and next two layout2 and so on.Please tell me if I'm not able to explain my use case correctly.